# Creating Quote-Like Shorthand in Racket

Tags: syntax, scheme, racket

In Lisp/Scheme, one very common shorthand for wrapping a form in `quote` is by prefixing the form with a single quote (ex. `(quote (a b c)` -> `'(a b c)`).

If I wanted to make my own Racket shorthand like this, that instead wraps the prefixed form with, for example, partial application, how would I accomplish this?

I'm very vaguely familiar with the concept of the reader in the read-eval-print succession, does it have to do with this?

Comment: This is a bigger question than perhaps you anticipated, but it involves making a new `#lang`, since the `#lang` mechanism is what controls the reader. I wish there was a better centralized source of documentation for doing something like this, but unfortunately there isn’t really, and I haven’t  got around to writing some. [The source code to my `curly-fn` package might help a little, though.](https://github.com/lexi-lambda/racket-curly-fn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the existing reader. The tool you need is called "reader-macros".

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/readtables.html?q=reader

Alex Knauth has made a library to make these things easier.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/hygienic-reader-extension/index.html